# Загрузочное устройство из образа диска на Андроид-устройстве

Tags: android, boot, iso-образ

Есть замечательное приложение DriveDroid, что позволяет с помощью Android загружать ПК из iso/img образов.  Мне очень интересно, как оно это делает? И можно ли это упростить до sh-скрипта?

Comment: оно это никак не делает, это телефон работает в режиме USB Mass Storage Device, а програмка эта просто копирует образ, но его можно и внешней программой записать

Comment: @PavelGridin, то есть, Вы хотите сказать, что если на sdcard будет записан, скажем какой-нибудь линукс, то подключив смартфон к компу и загрузившись, смарт отобразится в меню загрузки компа? Ой как сомневаюсь. Куда копирует? Или в какой loop монтирует?

Comment: ну вы физически не можете из андроид-программы поменять логику работы usb-slave контроллера

Comment: @PavelGridin, разшарив образ через DriveDroid и подключив его к компу, смартфон видно в бут-меню.